# Downloading Ubuntu: wich version to download?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, cpu-architecture

for a 32bit/2GRAM Dell Laptop, i'll be required to download the Ubuntu 64bit or the 32bit

version? Looking forward for help, and thank's for the support!